# What meaning does "should have" express in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

> Then there's another thing. I had hoped you might have peddled that opium through the islands, which is safer and more profitable. But with this three-month limit, you must make tracks for Honolulu straight, and communicate by steamer. I'll try to put up something for you there; I'll have a man spoken to who's posted on that line of biz. Keep a bright lookout for him as soon's you make the islands; for it's on the cards he might pick you up at sea in a whaleboat or a steam-launch, and bring the dollars right on board.”
> It shows how much I had suffered morally during my sojourn in San Francisco, that even now when our fortunes trembled in the balance, **I should have consented** to become a smuggler—and (of all things) a smuggler of opium. Yet I did, and that in silence; without a protest, not without a twinge.

(From The Wrecker by R. L. Stevenson and L. Osbourne, [chapter X. passage 154/155](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_10), published 1892)

What does *should have* express there? Should can express different meanings. I'm not sure what meaning of *should* fits this context.

**Editing:**

I've looked "should" up in my grammar book *English Grammar Today* (Cambridge University Press): It has this:

> **Should: uses**
>
> **. . .**
>
> ***Surprise or regret***
>
> We sometimes use *should* to express surprise or regret about something that happened:
>
> *I’m amazed that he **should have** done something so stupid.*
>
> *I’m sorry that he **should** be so upset by what I said.*

I surmise *should* expresses both surprise and regret in this context. I think that could make up a good answer.

Comment: The words ***should have*** as cited don't really mean anything (nothing changes if they're removed). It's a kind of "optional subjunctive", as in *I'm shocked! To think he **should have** said that!* rather than plain *To think he said that!* A literary flourish, if you will.

Comment: I should have consented to become a smuggler because "in fact didn't consent to it". should have done something. Where's the problem? The question is not "should have", it's "should have + past participle". here" regret about NOT doing something.

Comment: I think you're misreading it @Lambie. He _did_ consent to it. He's regretting that.

Comment: In more modern English this *should* would be *would*.

Comment: I should have consented to become a smuggler—and (of all things) a smuggler of opium.=the sentence. That means he agreed to become one? I think it's he didn't **but then** even so, "yet I did".

Comment: I should have consented to become a banker, a banker of all things, only for the rich. **Yet I did**. First no, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

The Cambridge Dictionary has [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/should) entry that seems most applicable:

> Mainly UK: used after "that" and adjectives or nouns that show an
> opinion or feeling:
>
> - It's so unfair that she *should have* died so young.

From context, it should be clear that the feeling or opinion that the narrator expresses is judgmental of his choices.

> It shows…**that**, even now when our fortunes trembled in the balance,
> **I should have consented to become a smuggler**…

The use of *should* in this way lends a casual wryness to the thought that might be absent if a different definition were used.

- *…even now when our fortunes trembled in the balance*

This phrase at the heart of the passage, neatly separating *that* from *I should*, is what sets the context for the passage. Based on what surrounds it, the phrase suggests that the narrator under normal circumstances would act conservatively when stakes are high. He attributes a shift in his moral compass to be what allows him to behave contrary to his nature. If he were acting in a way that was consistent with his former moral self, he would not consent to become a smuggler, much less a smuggler of opium to which he has a particular aversion.

The last sentence suggests that his passive acceptance *without protest* is not without pain. Perhaps, this is acknowledgement (pride?) that he was not so far gone that he was numb to his predicament at the time.

> It shows how much I had suffered morally during my sojourn in San
> Francisco, that even now when our fortunes trembled in the balance, I
> should have consented to become a smuggler—and (of all things) a
> smuggler of opium. Yet I did, and that in silence; without a protest,
> not without a twinge.